# Combined-Dictionary attack with hashcat, for 4 words passphrases?

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat, dictionary

Reading the [new advice on password](https://www.reddit.com/r/pwned/comments/6s7uv2/wsj_the_man_who_wrote_those_password_rules_has_a/) which seems to spead easily (at least in my workplace), I was wondering how to use hashcat for cracking four-word password hashes?

Say I have this hash `1da9133ab9dbd11d2937ec8d312e1e2569857059e73cc72df92e670928983ab5` of a password a user claims to be unbreakable because it's a 16 character long "passphrase", how can I combine hashcat's dictionaries to crack it (say I suspect it's a four-word password only)? I see you can [combine 2 dictionaries](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=combinator_attack) so you can crask 2 words passphrases, but what about 4?

The only way I see so far is creating another dictionary with all combinations of 2 words from the original English dictionary, and then do a combination attack using this "2words" dictionary twice (so it makes it a four-word dictionary):

```
./combinator.bin dict.txt dict.tdt > dict2words.txt
./hashcat64.bin -m 0 -a 1 hash.txt dict2words.txt dict2words.txt
```

But it feels heavy to generate such a `dict2words.txt` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for hashcat's related tool [princeprocessor](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=princeprocessor), also by hashcat's author. It's specifically designed for multiword passphrases and similar "combination" work.

A killer PRINCE feature is that it does all of the combination work for you *without having to store all combinations on disk* (which is probably what you meant by "heavy"?)

`princeprocessor` also includes [some hashcat rules](https://github.com/hashcat/princeprocessor/tree/master/rules) that are designed to maximize GPU utilization by adding a variety of permutations.

Tip: tinker with very short wordlists and observe the output directly:

```
$ cat wordlist.txt
xenos
hashcat
prince
passphrase

$ pp64 --elem-cnt-min=4 --elem-cnt-max=4 wordlist.txt
xenosxenosxenosxenos
xenosxenosxenosprince
xenosxenosprincexenos
xenosprincexenosxenos
princexenosxenosxenos
xenosxenosxenoshashcat
xenosxenosprinceprince
xenosprincexenosprince

[...]
passphraseprincehashcatxenos
passphrasehashcatxenosxenos
hashcatpassphraseprincexenos
passphrasehashcatprincexenos
```

... and then once it's working the way you expect, pipe your output to `hashcat` using wordlist mode (`-a 0`) with your real wordlist.

Comment: It's indeed what I was looking for. I only didn't think that the pipe attack was so slow (`pp64 ... | hashcat64`= 5MH/s while `hashcat -a 1 -m 1400 ... dico.txt dico.txt` = 380MH/s) I suppose I loose a lot of parallelization when using pipe?

Comment: Yep - you can do more "work" by supplying rules - but if it's a straight wordlist and you know the wordlist, the case, etc. then rules won't help much. Though for short wordlists, you *can* also generate a ruleset which basically simulates adding another word to the end, which could speed things up quite a bit.